# Counting certain products of permutations that are equal to the identity

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

Where $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, $\pi_3$ are elements of the symmetric group $S_n$, I'm interested in computing the following sum:
$$
f(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)
=
\sum_{\widetilde{\pi}_1\in S_n}\sum_{\widetilde{\pi}_2\in S_n}\sum_{\widetilde{\pi}_3\in S_n}\delta(\widetilde{\pi}_1\pi_1\widetilde{\pi}^{-1}_1\widetilde{\pi}_2\pi_2\widetilde{\pi}^{-1}_2\widetilde{\pi}_3\pi_3\widetilde{\pi}^{-1}_3,\mathrm{id}).
$$
Here $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity element of $S_n$ and $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta. Note that $f$ is manifestly invariant under conjugation of $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, or $\pi_3$, so it is a function only of the cycle structures of $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, and $\pi_3$. In particular, let $a^{(1)}_k$ be the number of cycles of size $k$ in the cycle decomposition of $\pi_1$. (Define $a^{(2)}_k$ and $a^{(3)}_k$ similarly.) I'm specifically after **a formula for $f(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$ in terms of the numbers $a^{(i)}_k$**.

Something I've thought of: you can rewrite $f$ in terms of irreducible characters as
$$
f(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)=n!^2\sum_q\frac{1}{d_q}\chi_q(\pi_1)\chi_q(\pi_2)\chi_q(\pi_3),
$$
where $q$ labels irreducible characters $\chi_q$, and $d_q=\chi_q(\mathrm{id})$ is the dimension of the $q$-th representation. From here you can write $\chi_q$  in terms of the $a_k$ using [character polynomials](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v16i2r19/pdf). This doesn't really satisfy what I'm trying to do, however, for two reasons: (1) it seems difficult to work out the character polynomials for large $n$, and (2) I'd really like a formula that works for all $n$.

To be clear about what I'm looking for, consider the generalization of $f$ to two arguments. You can get the following formula for the two-argument case
$$
f(\pi_1,\pi_2)
=
\sum_{\widetilde{\pi}_1\in S_n}\sum_{\widetilde{\pi}_2\in S_n}\delta(\widetilde{\pi}_1\pi_1\widetilde{\pi}^{-1}_1\widetilde{\pi}_2\pi_2\widetilde{\pi}^{-1}_2,\mathrm{id})
=
n!\prod_k a^{(1)}_k!k^{a^{(1)}_k}\delta_{a^{(1)}_k,a^{(2)}_k}
.
$$
I want a formula like this, but for the three-argument function $f(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$.

In the end I'd be interested in the generalizations of $f$ to more than three arguments, but those can be reduced to the 3-argument case. For example
$$
f(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3,\pi_4)=\frac{1}{n!^2}\sum_{\pi\in S_n}f(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi)f(\pi^{-1},\pi_3,\pi_4).
$$

Comment: Why do you think you will get something reasonable. Did you try $S_3, S_4, S_5$?

Comment: This may be a bad reason, but the fact that the two-argument sum works out nicely in terms of cycle structures made me suspect that the three-argument sum might possibly as well. As for computing explicit values, you can do that for any particular $n$ and permutations $\pi_i$, and from there you could brute force a function that works for the values you've calculated, but without some ansatz for what the general formula should look like, you wouldn't be likely to land on it. For what it's worth I've computed various values and haven't found too many helpful patterns.

Comment: There will be a formula, but it will likely be horrific. The reason there will be a formula is that the number of pairs $(\pi_1,\pi_2)$, $\pi_i$ from conjugacy class $C_i$, such that $\pi_1\pi_2=\pi_3$ is given by a formula based on character values and centralizers. So you can work this thorugh to get the answer, but I won't do that.

Comment: I'm guessing the formula you are thinking of is my second equation above. I don't expect to get much from this, as rewriting the formula in terms of the cycle counts $a_k$, via character polynomials, seems difficult. That is not to say that the answer you get in the end will be something nasty, however, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $\pi_1\pi_2=e$ is equivalent to $\pi_1=\pi_2^{-1}$, which is nice in this context because inversion plays nicely with conjugacy classes (indeed, in $S_n$ it fixes conjugacy classes). The equation $\pi_1\pi_2\pi_3=e$ on the other hand is equivalent to $\pi_1\pi_2=\pi_3^{-1}$, which is not nice for us because multiplication does not play nice with conjugacy classes: it is difficult to describe (in general) how often a permutation of cycle type $\lambda$ is produced by multiplying permutations of cycle types $\mu$ and $\nu$.

---

Let $C(\pi)$ be the centralizer of $\pi$. Your first formula is

$$ f(\pi_1,\pi_2)=\begin{cases} |G||C(\pi)| & \pi_1\sim\pi_2 \\ 0 & \pi_1\not\sim\pi_2 \end{cases} $$

which is not hard to see by counting: pick anything for $\bar{\pi}_1$, then the valid $\bar{\pi}_2$ for $\bar{\pi}_1\pi_1\bar{\pi}_1^{-1}=\bar{\pi}_2\pi_2^{-1}\bar{\pi}_2^{-1}$ are in a coset of $C(\pi_2^{-1})$ (which is conjugate to $C(\pi_2)$ since $\pi_2^{-1}\sim\pi_2$). The explicit formula for the size of a centralizer is classical, indeed $C(\pi)$ is a direct product of wreath products $C_k\wr S_{c_k(\pi)}$, where $C_k$ is cyclic (generated by a $k$-cycle) and $c_k(\pi)$ is the number of $k$-cycles in $\pi$.

Let $K(\pi)$ be the conjugacy class of $\pi$, so $|C(\pi)||K(\pi)|=|S_n|$ by orbit-stabilizer. The map $G\to K(\pi_1)$ given by $\bar{\pi}_1\mapsto \bar{\pi_1}\pi_1\bar{\pi}_1^{-1}$ is a $|C(\pi_1)|$-to-$1$ map. Therefore we may rewrite

$$ f(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)=|C(\pi_1)||C(\pi_2)||C(\pi_3)|g(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3), $$

$$ g(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3):=\#\{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)\in K(\pi_1)\times K(\pi_2)\times K(\pi_3)\mid \sigma_1\sigma_2=\sigma_3\} $$

or more simply (note $K(\pi_3^{-1})=K(\pi_3)$),

$$ g(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)=\#\{(\alpha,\beta)\in K(\pi_1)\times K(\pi_2)\mid \alpha\beta\in K(\pi_3)\} . $$

Abusing notation, we may view $K(\pi)$ as the sum of permutations from $\pi$\s conjugacy class as an element of the group ring center $Z(\mathbb{Z}[G])$. Or $K_\lambda$, if we use cycle types $\lambda$. Indeed, these sums form a nice integral basis. Then $K_\mu K_\nu = \sum C_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda} K_\lambda$ for some structure constants $C_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$, called connection coefficients. Summing all the coefficients of elements of $K_{\lambda}$ on both sides of this equation yields $g(\mu,\nu)=C_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}|K_{\lambda}|$.

Therefore it suffices to figure out these coefficients $C_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$, which is discussed in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62088/products-of-conjugacy-classes-in-s-n).